# UserControl twice inherited (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, c#-4.0, user-controls

I'm creating something like tool system similar to 3dsmax tool system. So, I have DockPanel, which is container for DockTool objects. But I would to have custom DockTool classes (DockTool  base class is UserControl). So, for each new tool, I'm creating new class based on DockTool.
Unfortunatelly when I put my DockTool objects in the List and from here later I insert them on form, they looks like pure DockTool, but I expect to see the final instance (corresponding to inheritance model), not the base classes with each case. How to solve that? THanks.

Comment: Try to force the cast it you're List is List<Control> like (DockTool)(List[i]);